# fade in background image when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery to change the background image when hovering on the text. I want to add a fade in effect.

here is the code I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#anatomyNow").hover(function(){
        $("#bg").css("background-image",    "url(image/anatomyNow5.png)");
        }, function(){
        $("#bg").css("background-image",    "url(image/anatomyNow5.png)");
        });
});
```

I tried to add the code below but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#anatomyNow").hover(function(){
        $("#bg").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Update:
Thank you all for answering.

The effect I want is something like this:
https://www.christinewalthall.com/work

When you hover over the text, the background image will change. I have managed to do that, but the image changed too fast. I hope to add the effect so the image does not change dramatically.

Comment: Perhaps its just fading too fast. Try changing fadeIn() to fadeIn(3000)

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work

Comment: fadeIn animates `opacity` not background image so it would make sense that that doesn't work :)

Comment: You're probably looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u92s6bym/?

Answer (score 0):

`fadeIn` animates the opacity of an element, so using it in this context wouldn't work.

There's probably more than one way to achieve what you want here, but the one that comes to mind is layering images/divs with background images on top of each other and using css opacity transition on hover.

I did a bit of googling for you and here's a resource that shows how to go about that:
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Answer (score 0):

**If I don't misunderstood your requirements** then this is something you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#effect").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: '1'
    }, "slow");
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: '0.5'
    }, "slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#effect {
  padding: 0.4em;
  background: #555 url("https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/77318/1007648908/stock-photo-sunrise-beam-in-the-beautiful-park-1007648908.jpg");
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#effect {
  max-width: 490px;
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
```